# C- How to copy a pointers value into non-pointer

Tags: c

So, i am using a code to replace strings. But but it has to be like this

```
char *a = "s0me string";
char *b = repl_str(a,"0",o");
printf(b);
```

It is working, but i want to use it as a non-pointer. So is there a way to copy a pointer value to non-pointer?
i want to do this

```
char *a = "* string";
char *b = repl_str(a,"*","a");
char c[]=b;
printf(c);
```

Obviously last code is not working. I get this error :

```
s.c:93:10: error: invalid initializer  
 char c[]=b;
```

I am using this code [from here](https://creativeandcritical.net/str-replace-c) for replace command.
Btw im new to this so if i made a mistake while describing my problem, im sorry.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using a VLA (Variable Length Array):

```
char *ptr = "Some string";
char str[strlen(ptr) + 1];

strcpy(str, ptr);
puts(str);
```

But you can not assign a value directly (you need to copy the contents using `strcpy`), in other words: [an array is not a modifiable lvalue](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `repl_str` modifies the string in-place.

```
char a[] = "* string";
char *b = &a[0];
repl_str(b,"*","a");
printf(a);
```